# How do I add items inside a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I am trying to write a `for` loop that adds the total budget of the films presented in a list.

How do I add the column of numbers in that list?

```py
def get_records():
 film_list = []  #start of list, 
 film_list.append(['FM01', 'Stealth', 135, 80])
 film_list.append(['FM02', 'Supernova', 90, 15])
 film_list.append(['FM03', 'Robin Hood', 100, 85])
 film_list.append(['FM04', 'Rollerball', 70, 26])
 film_list.append(['FM05', 'Rust', 85, 20])
 return film_list
```

The first column is the id of each movie, the second is the title, and the third is the budget.

Which operator will add the budget column so that 135, 90, 100, 70, and 85 are added together?

Comment: If `numbers = []` and `row = ['FM01', 'Stealth', 135, 80]`, then `numbers.append(row[2])` will make `numbers == [135]`. The `[2]` gets the thing at index 2 out of that list (counting starts from zero).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The integers you want to add up are at index 2 of each list. So, you can use `sum()` and a generator comprehension to get:

```py
sum(item[2] for item in film_list)
```

to get:

```py
480
```

---

If you *must* use a `for` loop, do the following:

```py
total = 0
for item in film_list:
    total += item[2]
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer but this doesn't seem to work. ```def get_total_budget_loss(data):

   for rec in data:
    sum(rec[2] for rec in data)
   print(sum)
    ```

Comment: What isn't working? The `for` loop isn't necessary, and you're not assigning the result of the call of `sum()` to a variable.

Comment: I am supposed to use a loop for this work, I have a problem with displaying the sum as an output. How do I do that?

Comment: See my recent edit.